# Замена в VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Как заменить несколько строчек кода во всей папке в VS Code. То есть у меня есть 200 HTML страниц. Необходимо сразу на всех изменить код шапки. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Открываем папку, и там Ctrl+Shift+H

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133960/discussion-on-answer-by-denis-i---vs-code).